# Adding refrence to 'Xamarin.Android.Crashlytics' causes multiple compile time errors

Tags: firebase, xamarin.forms, compiler-errors, xamarin.android, crashlytics

When adding a reference through Nuget to Xamarin.Android.Crashlytics version 2.9.4.3 for my Xamarin.Android project I receive a whole host of compile time errors:

[image]

Please can anyone help with these issues? Thanks in advance:)

Comment: googling any of those errors should return multiple suggestions

Comment: @Sach,I try to install Xamarin.Android.Crashlytics on xamarin.Form for Android, but I don't have any issue when compiling or build, According to your error message, I guess that it is not Xamarin.Android.Crashlytics reason.

Comment: Must be an issue with another reference which is causing the conflict. But not sure which references and how to even resolve this

Comment: @Sach K,According to your error message, I guess that there is some issue in Android values, so you add some xml in values? can you share here?

Comment: The values.xml file is auto-generated

Comment: In case you haven't found this, might be helpful: https://alexduffell.wordpress.com/2018/06/26/using-crashlytics-with-xamarin-apps/